# GNUPG decryption failed in php

Tags: php, gnupg, pgp

I am using GnuPG library to encrypt decrypt messages. I have successfully confirgured the GPG extension on my server and generated a key pair. Also I am successfull in importing another public key and enrypting data using that public key.

I also encrypted data using my public key and decrypted it using my private key.

But when somebody else encrypts data using my public key I am unable to decrypt it. the error is

```
Warning: gnupg_decrypt(): decrypt failed in pgpdecrypt.php on line 22
```

my code is

```
$Message = $_REQUEST["Message"];

// Specify custom location of GnuPG binary.
$res = gnupg_init();

gnupg_seterrormode($res, GNUPG_ERROR_WARNING); 

$rtv = gnupg_adddecryptkey($res, "rizwan@google.com", "0000");
echo gnupg_geterror($res) . "<br>"; // Print if any errors

$enc = gnupg_decrypt($res, $Message); // ERROR IS AT THIS LINE
echo gnupg_geterror($res) . "<br>"; // Print if any errors
echo $enc;
```

this same code is decrypting data encrypted by me at my machine.

I am unable to extract error details.

Comment: Are you sure the other people are correctly encrypting it?

Comment: Yes I am sure, because I am using a third party web app to decrypt data using my private key and passphrase and that web app is decrypting the encryted text.

this is the website I am using
https://www.igolder.com/pgp/decryption/

Comment: Never use a 3rd party system/app/service etc to decrypt your data. What's the point in having a private key if you just hand it out to any shady website?

Comment: we are just testing at the moment.

I dig into it and found following error
**cipher algorithm 6 is unknown or disabled** hope you can help

Comment: The GnuPG PECL extension was last updated in 2010-07-20. It is very likely it is not compatible with current PHP versions. You should instead use the PEAR package http://pear.php.net/package/Crypt_GPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cipher Algorithm 6 reffers to DES. DES is not supported in GnuPG, it uses 3DES/Triple-DES instead. I encrypted the data using 3DES and it successfuly decrypted at my site.

Hope this helps to other people encountering same problem. :)